# Boxing type equality and dictionary keys

Tags: c#, dictionary, equality, boxing

I have a bit of confusion about how dictionary compare keys when it comes to boxed types.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                
public class Program
{
     public static void Main()
     {
           int i = 5;
           int n = 5;
           
           object boxedI = i;
           object boxedN = n;
           
           Console.WriteLine("i == n ? " + (i == n) ); //true
           Console.WriteLine("bI == bN ? " + (boxedI == boxedN) ); //false
           
           Dictionary<object,int> _dict = new Dictionary<object,int> ();
           _dict.Add(boxedI,5);
           
           Console.WriteLine("_dict contains boxedI? " + _dict.ContainsKey(boxedI) ); //true
           Console.WriteLine("_dict contains boxedN? " + _dict.ContainsKey(boxedN) ); //!! also true, surprise me
           
           _dict.Add(boxedN,5);//exception
     }
}
```

I expected that since equality operator "failed" (AFAIK it's based on method GetHashCode the same method dictionary use to build it's internal hashtable form objects) then also the dictionary should "fail" the comparison of boxed I and N, but that's not the case.

Here the fiddle I use: https://dotnetfiddle.net/DW54nN

So I am asking if someone can explain to me what append here and what I am missing in my mental model.

Comment: This is a reference vs value type thing, when you use object it turns into a value, so when you compare them they compare the reference (which the two references of boxedI and boxedN are not the same) where as when you use `_dict.ContainsKey(boxedN)` it uses the value inside the reference type

Comment: Well, more importantly it uses Equals and GetHashCode. If you call `boxedI.Equals(boxedN)` that will return true, and if you call GetHashCode on them both, they'll return the same values.

Comment: @JonSkeet so my mistake is to assume that == operand is equivalent to Equals are equivalent (just read a post about that on C# corer).  Thanks concise and clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR: Comparing boxed values using `==` uses reference equality of the boxing object, but comparing boxed values using `Equals()` uses the underlying values' `Equals()`.

---

When a value type is boxed, the boxing object's `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` method implementations call the boxed value's versions.

That is, given:

- A value type `VT` that implements `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` correctly.
- An instance `x` of `VT`.
- An instance `y` of `VT` with the same value as `x`.
- A boxed instance of `x`: `bx`.
- A boxed instance of `y`: `by`.

The following will be the case:

```
x.Equals(y)      == true             // Original values are equal
bx.Equals(by)    == true             // Boxed values are equal
x.GetHashCode()  == y.GetHashCode()  // Original hashes are equal
bx.GetHashCode() == by.GetHashCode() // Boxed hashes are equal
bx.GetHashCode() == x.GetHashCode()  // Original hash code == boxed hash code
```

**However, the `==` operator is NOT delegated by the boxed version**, and in fact it is implemented using *reference* equality, so:

```
(x == y)   == true  // Original values are equal using "=="
(bx == by) == false // Boxed values are not equal using "=="
ReferenceEquals(bx, by) == false // References differ
```

The Dictionary is using `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` for comparing objects, and because they delegate to the underlying values it works correctly.

---

This is demonstrated by the following program:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    struct MyStruct: IEquatable<MyStruct>
    {
        public int X;

        public bool Equals(MyStruct other)
        {
            return X == other.X;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (obj is not MyStruct other)
                return false;

            return X == other.X;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return -X;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var x = new MyStruct { X = 42 };
            var y = new MyStruct { X = 42 };
            object bx = x;
            object by = y;

            Console.WriteLine(bx.GetHashCode()); // -42
            Console.WriteLine(y.GetHashCode()); // -42

            Console.WriteLine(bx.Equals(by)); // True
            Console.WriteLine(bx == by); // False
            Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(bx, by)); // False
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a reference vs value type thing:

```
int i = 5;
int n = 5;
```

These are value types and get put on the stack, so when we compare them we go to the stack and can say that the value of i and n are 5 which make them "equal".

```
object boxedI = i;
object boxedN = n;
```

When you put these values in an `object` you create a "reference" type which means that a value gets put into the heap, and a reference gets put on the stack so you can imagine that on the stack you have:

```
#0005 -> boxedI
#0006 -> boxedN
```

now when you do the equals you are comparing `#0005 == #0006` which are not the same

but when you pass `boxedI` or `boxedN` into `ContainsKey` that method knows how to follow the reference (or pointer) to the value that is on the heap (5).

so when you ask for `ContainsKey(boxedI)` what you're doing is asking for `ContainsKey(5)` (in rough terms)

that's why that those two are "equal"

Comment: Yes, i would add just few word about how my mistake originated. I wrongly assumed that the '==' operator is just a shorthand for Equal() operator. 
The former compare references, the latter compare values and so the bheavoiour is different from what i am expecting.

Comment: [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) and *entirely* irrelevant to the question. It's all about the semantics of reference vs value types, which could equally apply to stack-allocated refs and/or heap-allocated values

Comment: @Charlieface I was explaining why the poster was seeing a difference between comparing two value types and two reference types, I fail to see how you do that without talking about the stack, I don't think it's "entirely irrelevant" as you say. Just an easy way to explain why the difference exists in an abstract way

Comment: It is absolutely irrelevant. The difference between them is not whether it goes on the stack, it's that reference and value types have different *semantics* and defined *behaviours*: one has reference semantics (new values refer to old values), the other copy semantics (new values are cloned). Any case, that isn't the problem in this OP, the actual problem is that `==` on an `object` type will do a reference comparison, whereas theoretically you could call `Equals` on a boxed value type and get the correct output (although the CLR and C# don't support variables defined as a boxed value type)